# Mean and Rep function in Random number generation

Tags: r, random, mean

```
x<-rnorm(12, mean=rep(1:3,each=4), sd=0.2)
```

Can someone please explain the translation of the above statement? Why do we specify `rep(1:3)` and `each=4` here?

Comment: it is just to specify the `mean` as a vector of values i.e. in the output you get values taken from random normal distribution with mean value of 1 for the 4 elements, 2 for the next 4 elements, and so on .

Comment: thank you very much